# name 'scale_to_img' is not defined. Where I can find the Modul?

Tags: matplotlib, openstreetmap

I followed this:
[https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-gps-data-visualization-using-python-and-open-street-maps-50f992e9b676][1]

and geht the error:

```
name 'scale_to_img' is not defined
```

Can some tell my where i can find the Module. Is it a Part of PIL?

Thanks
and Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the comments on [that article](https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-gps-data-visualization-using-python-and-open-street-maps-50f992e9b676) the writer points to the `scale_to_img` function being in their Github repo. You can find that actual function (which in their case is actually a class method) [here](https://github.com/tisljaricleo/GPS-visualization-Python/blob/main/gps_class.py#L63).

Comment: Oh great... I should read it more carefully.